# early exit with shift and reset

Tags: scheme, continuations, delimited-continuations

Trying to understand delimited continuations with Guile scheme

I managed to grasp the vanilla conts (call/cc) thanks to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ju3KKu_mthg&t=39s) video (it's great)

Now I'd like to move to delimited conts

I have this minimal example of early exit made with call/cc

```
(define (my-early-exit)
  (let ((
     my-val (call/cc
         (lambda (the-continuation)
           (display "this will be executed")
           (display "\n")
           (the-continuation 5) ;;early exit
           (display "this will not be executed")))))
    (display my-val)))
```

Ok, I can run this, I understand what it does

How can I write a piece of code equivalent to this one using shift and reset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused about `shift` and `reset` but this is how I understand it, based on some notes I made on a little while ago.  I'd welcome clarification and/or correction people who understand this better than I do.

The equivalent thing, more or less, would be

```
(define (mee/sr)
  (reset
   (display "this will happen\n")
   (shift k 5)
   (display "this won't happen, unless you call k\n")))
```

So, here (if I understand this!):

- `reset` establishes a 'place you can get to' in a similar way that `call/cc` does, except that there is no explicit variable for it;
- `(shift k ...)` will:

  1. reset to the dynamically-nearest `reset`;
  2. evaluate `...` with `k` bound to a continuation (? name) which, if called, will return its argument values from the `shift` form and then continue after it.

So in this case I am not using `k` at all, so the forms after the `shift` never happen.  But in this case:

```
(define (another)
  (reset
   (display "here\n")
   (let ((v (shift k (k "and here\n"))))
     (display v))
   (display "and finally here as well\n")))
```

Then

```
> (another)
here
and here
and finally here as well
```

And lest this all seem too obvious:

```
(define (yet-another)
  (reset
   (display "here\n")
   (let ((v (shift k
                   (k "and here\n")
                   (displayln "there is also Sheemish\n"))))
     (display v))
   (display "and finally here as well\n")))
```

then

```
> (yet-another)
here
and here
and finally here as well
there is also Sheemish
```

There is a good amount of information on `shift` and `reset` [here](https://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/#tutorial), although I do not completely understand them.